# anam-hossain/captcha working localy using valet but not on forge -> DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-forge

I installed the captcha swiftly on my local computer where I use valet. When I deployed it to the server it does not work. It is just showing the text:

> @captcha()

where the acctual captcha box shows on my local comp.

I did run composer install on the server and the package is required on the server and seem to be installed as I can find it in the vendor.

What can this be?

Comment: Did you remember to run `composer update`?

Comment: what is the php version on your server?